# Reverse opertion involving bitwise SHIFT and AND operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, rgb, bitwise-operators

I'm new to C. I have a function that converts three `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` (r, g, and b) each one representing a colour value for red, blue and green respectively. I have a function that converts them into R5B6G5 format. This format is used to store a colour on a 16 bit unsigned integer. That means that the first (from the left) 5 bits are used the store the value of red (r), the next 6 bits for green (g) and the last 5 one for blue. The function:

```
uint16_t R5G6B5(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
    return ((r >> 3) << 11) | ((g >> 2) << 5) | (b >> 3);
}
```

My question is how can I get back the three values of r (red), g (green) and b (blue) from a given `uint16_t`. My understanding is that I can't because the bitwise or operation is not reversible. But the application seems to be able to display colours from this format, so I assume it is somehow able to retrieve the three values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function converts RGB888 (that's 8 bit for every color) to the RGB565 (6 bits for GREEN and 5 bits for the other colors. You cannot recover the lower bits lost in the conversion.

The application might be able to show the image, but this is less precise image than original one. You may do a reverse conversion, but again, you have lost 2-3 lower bits, so your image will never be the same.

The backward conversion can be done like this:

```
uint16_t rgb565 = some value;
uint8_t red = (rgb565 >> 11) << 3;
uint8_t green = ((rgb565 >> 5) << 2) & 0xFF;
uint8_t blue = (rgb565 << 3) & 0xFF;
```

And yeah, you should not worry about OR operation, because in your case the operands are never overlapping, so there's no loss if the information during the OR operation.

Comment: "You cannot recover the lower bits lost in the conversion." is true for a single pixel.  Various schemes can dither or average the lost bits and restore a slight improvement for the overall picture.  Agree information is lost.